# Why I'm getting Javassist objects in the middle of a result set?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, javassist

I'm having an strange problem when I try to retrieve some entities from the database. The table where the entities lives just have 4 rows. When I try select all rows I get a list where the first and the last elements are loaded correct, however, the second and the third has all properties as null. Here is a print of my debug console:

[image: javassist problem debug]

The entity is simple, as you can see below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Empresa")
public class Empresa implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_EMPRESA")
    private Integer idEmpresa;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NOME_EMPRESA")
    @OrderColumn
    private String nomeEmpresa;
    @Column(name = "CNPJ")
    private String cnpj;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "iDEmpresa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Cadastro> cadastroList;

}
```

If you want know how I am retrieving the entities, here is the code:

```
@Override
public List<T> recuperarTodos() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criarQueryRecuperarTodos());
    limitarQuantidadeDeRegistros(query);
    return query.getResultList();
}

private String criarQueryRecuperarTodos() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("SELECT e FROM ");
    builder.append(classe.getSimpleName());
    builder.append(" e");
    builder.append(criarParametrosOrdenacao());
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Those are proxies. Try setting your fetch to `EAGER`.

Comment: This is unacceptable in this case, notice that cadastroList of the first entity retrieved contains 1478 entities. If I use eager in this, I will have performance problems, once the Cadastro entity is a complex one and have some relationships with fetch eager

Comment: Did you solve this ? I'm facing the same issue !

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly legal and expected situation. Hibernate uses dynamically generated proxies (hence javaassist objects, in the past hibernate used cglib as well) as placeholders for not fully fetched entities to allow lazy fetching. Because of this, generally speaking, you should not attempt to access attribute values directly. Using getters instead allows hibernate to issue an appropriate DB query and fill the entity. This can be a problem in some situations - for example, if the values are first requested outside the Hibernate session.

Comment: Is there a way I can minimize this problem?

Comment: This usually is not an issue, if you use getters instead of plain field access, which I see you do. Do you actually see nulls during execution of your code, or just in the debug console? I suppose you do, and that's why you bothered to check it in the debug console. Perhaps it has to do with hibernate session lifetime? I'd expect LazyInitializationException in such case, though.

Comment: Try expand handler field of proxied object, you should see a copy of your `Empresa` object where data are filled with database values

Comment: @MarcinŁoś I use getters and setter in the entities, I just hid it to not make the code long. The occurence of nulls are really rare. What strikes me here is the fact that the two entities in the middle of the result are proxies.